# Turn off the screen completely dark on android

Tags: android, screen

How to code the android to turn the screen completely off just like you press the power button to lock your screen.

I have tried to use

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 0 )
```

The screen does deem to very dark but it still is emitting light.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this one:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
wl.acquire();
```

Also refer [this example](http://android.okhelp.cz/turn-screen-on-off-android-sample-code/).